# Dynamic text fields html form php

Tags: php, forms

I want to create a form, that when the user adds a number. It will display the input boxes based on the numbers they added. Then as I click the add button it will display the values in the added input boxes. I have added the dynamic ids/names for the post but to no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Tags</title>
</head>

<body>
<p></p>
<form name="add_tags" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tag_num" size="2" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="add_tag" value="Add Tag" style="border:dotted;" />
<p></p>

<?php
$num_x="";
$post=array();
$tag="tag";
if(isset($_POST['add_tag'])){
//Adding values to a tag
$num_x=$_POST['tag_num'];
$tag="tag";
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
for($x=0;$x<$num_x;$x++){
echo $input=$tag.$x."<br>";
$post[]=$input;
echo "add_tag => <input type=\"text\" name=$input  />";

echo "<br>";
}
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Add\" value=\"Add\" style=\"border:dotted;\"/>";
echo "</form>";
}
if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
$num_x = count($post);
for($x=0;$x<$num_x;$x++){
  $input=$tag.$x;
echo $_POST[$input]."<br>";
}
}
?>


</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like the below code using JQUERY,

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#formID').after().html('<input type="textbox" .... />');
});
```

Comment: This will run on page load. Also, what will be the value of `counter` in that case?

Comment: edited code check it. do u want to run on page load use like this or else add this code in function and call when you need.

Comment: I want to use if on page load